# Expected lifetime of system that fails with probability $p$ per week

Tags: probability

If the probability that a given system fails in a week is p, what is the expected lifetime of the system?

I have no clue how to approach this. I have been thinking about this for a while now. Basically I wanted to find out, if my laptop fails in a year with a low probability say 1/100, what is its expected lifetime? How do I compute the expected lifetime here? Is the data insufficient to answer this? I don't know how to approach this. I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Google "Geometric random variable".

Comment: The expected number of failures per week is $p$.  Expectations are additive, so you expect $np$ failures after $n$ weeks, and so the number of weeks you need to wait to expect one failure is $1/p$.  This is the expected lifetime of the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it.

Comment: There are several hidden assumptions in your problem.  The model mentioned by David Mitra assumes that the failure probability is constant, which is not true for many real-life systems: the older the system, the higher the probability that it will fail during the next week, month, year, etc. Also look for information on hazard rates.

Comment: Different components age in different ways, so the problem is quite complex. We can use a primitive exponential distribution model. But even if the probability that your new laptop fails in a year or less is $1/100$, I am confident it will be dead in $25$ years or less, something very different from what the exponential model would suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of failures per week is $p$. Expectations are additive, so you expect $np$ failures after $n$ weeks, and so the number of weeks you need to wait to expect one failure is $1/p$. This is the expected lifetime of the system.

You can add up $\sum_1^\infty np(1-p)^{n-1}$ as Emre suggested, but you will just get $1/p$ anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that it fails on the $n$'th week is that it does not fail in $n-1$ weeks *then* fails. Call this $P_n=p(1-p)^{n-1}$. The expected lifetime is therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n P_n$. You can take it from there...

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the system survives for exactly $n$ periods is $(1-p)^{n-1}p$. So the expected lifetime is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p$. Call this value $E$ (in principle, we would have to check that the series converges). Now with probability $p$ the system fails in the first round and with probability $(1-p)$ we are in the same situation as originally but one round later. So we have $E=p+(1-p)(E+1)$. Solving this gives you $E=1/p$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends strongly on context. If this is a routine  homework exercise, then one assumes, possibly without explicitly saying so, that the probability the thing dies in the next second is *independent* of how long it has lived.

Under that extremely dubious assumption, the length of life $T$ of the laptop has *exponential* distribution.  For $t \ge 0$, the probability that $T > t$ is $e^{-\lambda t}$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.

If you know, for example, that the probability of surviving at least $1$ year is $\frac{99}{100}$, then we can compute $\lambda$.

It turns out that the expected lifetime is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, so once we have found $\lambda$, the expected lifetime is immediate.  In our case we get about $99.5$ (years!).

**However**, the above model is not realistic if you are thinking of actual laptops. A new laptop has a fair probability of early death. If it survives for a few hours, the exponential distribution model gives, for a while, a fairly good fit. But in the long run, the exponential model fits very badly.

The exponential model is a model under which there is death but no aging. This model describes radioactive decay very well. But laptop components age, in various ways that are component-dependent. For example, the battery will almost certainly not hold a charge $5$ years from now.

The exponential model will predict a mean lifetime that is probably greater than the truth by a substantial factor. More plainly put, it will give an answer that is way off.

There is real information available about mean lifetime of laptops. It comes from concrete data, not a mathematical model.  One *can* find good mathematical models of lifetime, particularly at the component level. But the exponential distribution, or its discrete cousin the *geometric* distribution, are not suitable, though they are not too bad at the lowest level, for example, in the old days, at the transistor level.